# Save / Restore state of NestedScrollView with multiple RecyclerViews and other views

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview, kotlin, nestedscrollview

*Update:* This method works, only the saving didn't work, so I chose another way to save this array.

In my layout I have a NestedScrollView and in it a LinearLayout, which contains multiple RecyclerViews and other views. The layout is inside a Fragment.
I try to save and restore the scroll state the following way (it's Kotlin, so don't wunder about the syntax):

```
fun NestedScrollView.savePosition(bundle: Bundle?) {
    bundle?.putIntArray("SCROLL_VIEW_POSITION", intArrayOf(scrollX, scrollY))
}

fun NestedScrollView.restorePosition(bundle: Bundle?) {
    bundle?.getIntArray("SCROLL_VIEW_POSITION")?.let { post { scrollTo(it[0], it[1]) } }
}
```

I call the first function in `onSaveInstanceState` and the second one after all RecyclerViews have loaded their contents.

But it's not working...

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Could you please, give more details about, where you restore positions. I mean in default way you need to restore state of views and something like that or in `onRestoreInstanceState` or in `onCreate`. Where you call `NestedScrollView.restorePosition`?

Comment: I think NestedScrollView will destroy the recycling of your vertical RecyclerView.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to restore scroll position of NestedScrollView after pop back stack with fragment manager, you don't need to do it manually. For me the problem was in lack of **id** of NestedScrollView. After I added id in xml layout - everithing works well.